# why we use multiple catch when we can handle with parent exception

Tags: performance, exception, .net-core, try-catch

Exception handling provides the smooth flow of application but when we come to the technical part it's difficult to understand why we should use multiple catch blocks.When we can handle the exception by general parent exception using one catch block so why we need multiple catch

Comment: would you make your question a little more clear by adding some code samples of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

A multiple catch block is useful when you want to handle different exceptions in different ways.

```
try
{
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int result = num1 / num2;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
      Console.Write("Cannot divide by zero");
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
       Console.Write("Not a valid number");
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
      Console.Write("Not a valid number");
}
```

**When use multiple catch blocks**

- To print message specific to an exception
- To execute some logic specific to an exception